# How can I access a static-method only class via ScriptEngine?

Tags: java, nashorn, scriptengine

I have a class `Foo` that has only one static method (of note), called `bar()`. I need to access `bar()` via a runtime script (in this case Javascript).

```
final ScriptEngineManager factory;
factory = new ScriptEngineManager();

factory.put("foo", new Foo());
```

The above works, but it seems a bit odd to me. Specifically I don't want to create a new Foo. `Foo` is public, so there must be a way to let the script factory know about it, without instantiating a new object. I have tried `factory.put("foo", Foo.class);` but that didn't work. I also tried specifying the package in the Javascript code, eg.

```
package.Foo.bar();
```

but that didn't work either.

**Q:** Is there a way to access a class' static methods from an embedded script, without binding an instance of that class to the engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write the `Packages` keyword before the complete path of the class.
Example:

```
javax.script.ScriptEngine engine = 
        new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval("Packages.yourpackages.Foo.bar()");
```

**Documention** links in OpenJDK Wiki: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+Documentation

Here is something about the **Packages object**: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html

Comment: Wow, I'd never have guessed. Do you happen to have a URL to the official documentation? Searching for this one gets drowned with `package` noise

Comment: I add some links to dokumentions.